# new line character in fetchall() python

Tags: python, database

I am selecting data from a database in python.

```
cur.execute("Select a,b,c from tab1")
print "a,b,c"
print "\n"
data = cur.fetchall()
print "".join(str(e) for e in data).replace("(","").replace(")","")
```

I want to put a newline character at the end of each row.

Output should look like

```
a,b,c
A,B,C        //These values are from the database.
D,E,F
```

Thanks

Comment: What does the output look like?  does `'\n'.join(str(e) for e in data)` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
'\n'.join(str(e) for e in data)
```

instead of:

```
''.join(str(e) for e in data)
```

as the former command will insert a newline between each data string whereas the latter inserts an empty string (i.e. nothing).